# Next() is not being called on beforeRouteUpdate using the same component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am using the same vue-component to display data that I'm fetching with axios. After clicking on a link the ajax-request is fetching new data.

But if the component is already loaded and the user clicks another link to load different data, the `next()`-method is not called.

Check out my codepen to see what I mean. There should be an alert showing. If you click a link for the first time, it does. If you switch to another link, it does not.

https://codepen.io/spqrinc/pen/YzXGGGL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards):

> Note that `beforeRouteEnter` is the only guard that supports passing a callback to next. For `beforeRouteUpdate` and `beforeRouteLeave`, `this` is already available, so passing a callback is unnecessary and therefore not supported

So the `next()` in `beforeRouteUpdate` can't take a callback because you already have access to the instance in `this`.  Anything you would have done with `vm` in that callback can be done without it using `this`:

```
beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
  alert("Reloaded");
  // `this` works
  next();
}
```